# Connect old IBM Thinkpad monitor to Desktop PC?

Tags: display, thinkpad, vga

I have an old IBM Thinkpad laptop. It worked a few days before, but I decided to take off all the components (harddisk, cd-rom, keyboard) as the laptop was not useful at all. But, it has a shiny 15" monitor, which I would like to connect to a simple VGA port, to put on my wall for monitoring some servers.  But as far I know, there aren't any adapters that I could use to connect it to a display port (VGA, DVI, HDMI etc)?

Comment: It the laptop is usable, you could put a lightweight OS on it and use a remote desktop tool or X windows to run the monitoring software on another PC.  Otherwise you are looking to to some hardware hacking

Comment: unfortunately is not usable

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible, depending on exact laptop model. I use several laptop screens as desktop monitors. Search ebay for "Laptop LCD Converter". All you need is the model number of the screen, typically written on the back of the display in a format similar to "LTN154U1-L01". I have one 1440x1050 from a T41 and a 1920x1200 from a Dell hooked up like this.